# Good sample spring and hibernate web application book?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss

I am searching for book which have examples in enterprise web application with Spring (IoC, AOP, MVC, web services), Hibernate and JBoss. I am searching for just examples and explanations how this technologies works together and I am looking more for the backend parts like beans aop and web services (why to use jboss or just tomcat). I dont have lots of time but something like 300-400 pages is ok just to understand basics and see some real world examples and usages of this technologies. The best will be if I can found book with single big web application and usage of all of these technologies together (Spring IoC AOP web sevices, Hibernate, and JBoss).

Comment: How about Spring In Action (http://www.manning.com/walls5/), it helped me allot, when I just started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend Spring in Practice ([manning.com/wheeler](http://www.manning.com/wheeler/)) and Spring in Action (Walls). Former book is more a practical guide and probably best answer to your question, but Spring in Action will give you more of background information. Spring in Practice lacks a unittesting which is a serious ommision in my opinion.

Comment: I also need some real world open source web application when this technologies are used. Do you know something ?

Comment: @naskobg13 Maybe the maven archetype project https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype is something. Not so much of webservices, but quite useful with spring-security, thymeleaf, orm, java config. It is very up to date with spring version. You may also want to checkout the spring pet clinic.